# C# dataGridView_RowValidating() does not retain focus in the same row in which error exists, Why?

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, sqlexception

[image: Click here to see snapshot]

I have a form with DataGridView to update a table in database. I want to retain focus in the current row until the sql-error is cleared. I did it in the following way but the Problem is:

> *"Error is caught in the next row instead of the current row."*

Why is it so???

This is my Code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2601)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Ticket", "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this asp.net webforms? Window forms or wpf?

Comment: It is a window form. Snapshot link is given.